# Is the "probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics" and quantum randomness the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, randomness

Digital Physics are a branch of hypotheses about the fundamental physics of our universe. They basically describe the universe as an analogy to a computer and defend that everything in the universe is computable.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics)

Important proponents of these hypotheses, like nobel laureate Gerard 't Hooft, defend that...

> (...) the probabilistic nature of quantum physics is not necessarily incompatible with the notion of computability

But is this the same as quantum randomness? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability)

I've read everywhere that quantum randomness is utterly uncomputable*, so how can this be compatible with what these authors hold?

*for example here: https://books.google.es/books?id=gjf3BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=quantum+randomness+uncomputable&source=bl&ots=oyr7paY2Nm&sig=ACfU3U1ra3Dk0FLBbgCvr5RCXmA5aZ93Mg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3qMy1q7LhAhVO1hoKHU2SCWUQ6AEwCHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=quantum%20randomness%20uncomputable&f=false

Comment: Can you provide a more specific citation of how quantum mechanics is compatible with computability? Surely the probability distributions in quantum mechanics are computable. The only difficulty is then effectively sampling those probability distributions on a computer as is always the case with probablility distributions.

Comment: @Ian you said that the probability distributions are computable, but I've always read that quantum randomness is not computable. Are these two concepts (probability distributions and quantum randomness) the same?

Comment: Probability distributions in quantum mechanics are certainly computable.  The computation is exponentially complex, and it requires solving the Schrodinger equation exactly for a many-body system, but with enough computer time it is certainly possible.  Any undergraduate quantum mechanics textbook demonstrates several solvable problems in quantum mechanics that can even be solved by hand, and they certainly involve quantum randomness!

Comment: Now the problem is how to sample the resulting distributions.  Just like sampling a normal distribution on a computer requires a pseudo-random number generator, sampling quantum probability distributions may only be done pseudo-randomly on a computer.  I assume that it is in this sense that quantum randomness is not computable.

Comment: @Ian here there are some examples of texts that indicate that quantum randomness is uncomputable. Are these texts proposing what you are saying?: Example 1: https://books.google.es/books?id=gjf3BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=quantum+randomness+uncomputable&source=bl&ots=oyr7paY2Nm&sig=ACfU3U1ra3Dk0FLBbgCvr5RCXmA5aZ93Mg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3qMy1q7LhAhVO1hoKHU2SCWUQ6AEwCHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=quantum%20randomness%20uncomputable&f=false

Comment: @Ian Example 2: https://books.google.es/books?id=h8-PDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22quantum+randomness%22+%22uncomputable%22&source=bl&ots=KLqtme-CgU&sig=ACfU3U1j8-l1lPaah0h81fIz10TZdcUsxw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjipYSx9MPhAhWRyoUKHV7lDVIQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22quantum%20randomness%22%20%22uncomputable%22&f=false

Comment: The second book is a bit technical for me to understand.  However, I stand by my statement that the result of any measurement of a quantum phenomena is uncomputable, while the underlying probability distributions (wave functions) themselves are most definitely computable.

Comment: @Ian ai mway be wrong, but aren't there wave functions that are uncomputable, as it is said here: http://claesjohnson.blogspot.com/2015/08/popper-vs-physics-as-finite-precision.html?m=1?

Comment: Can you highlight the part of the article you want me to look at? With enough computer time one can solve for the wave functions of any quantum system up to some requested precision. I guess it depends on what you mean by computable.